# Docker command won't work unless I open an interactive bash terminal

Tags: selenium, docker, nightwatch.js

I'm using Docker to running automated browser testing using nightwatch.js

When I open an interactive terminal it works fine, e.g.

```
docker run -it --rm username/image-name /bin/bash
```

that gives me a bash prompt and I run:

```
xvfb-run node nightwatch.js
```

and everything works fine.

But when I run:

```
docker run --rm username/image-name xvfb-run node nightwatch.js
```

It just hangs.

*What's the difference between opening a bash terminal and manually running the test command, and just running the test command directly?  Surely they should both work?*

Comment: running `node nightwatch.js` might have different meaning inside and outside container. When running inside container it might have access to the project but outside the container, its a completely different area. You can include it in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Does it anyway help using option `-ti` for `docker run --rm username/image-name xvfb-run node nightwatch.js` as well?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but adding the -ti option doesn't help.  The container has access to the project by means of a mounted volume, e.g.  -v $(pwd):/tmp/

Comment: @simbro, what is the base image?

Comment: Hi @Rao, the base image is ubuntu:16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I still don't know what is causing this issue, but I have a workaround that works quite well:

Run bash as a daemon:

```
CONTAINERID=$(docker run -it -d username/image-name /bin/bash)
```

Then use *docker exec*:

```
docker exec $CONTAINERID xvfb-run node nightwatch.js
```

Of course you will need to do some tidying up afterwards:

```
docker stop $CONTAINERID
docker rm $CONTAINERID
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround I have found to work is putting your command in a script. For example:

```
$ echo "xvfb-run node nightwatch.js" >> tmp.sh
$ docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):your-workdir username/image-name tmp.sh
... expected output...
```

Assuming your script is accessible by the container, e.g. with -v as in the example above.